# Set multi buttons to disabled with a click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i have 4 buttons in my menu and when i click on one of them all should be set to disabled. Do you know how I can do this?

My Code:

```
 <div class="header-menu">
                    <!-- File search -->
                    <button type="button">
                      <i class="fa fa-search" matTooltip="Filter"></i>
                    </button>
                    <!-- File import -->
                    <button type="button">
                      <i class="fas fa-upload" matTooltip="SuSa-Upload" ></i>
                    </button>
                    <!-- File export -->
                    <button type="button">
                      <i class="fas fa-download" matTooltip="SuSa-Download"></i>
                    </button>
                    <!-- Start calculatoryBookings -->
                    <button type="button">
                      <i class="fas fa-edit"
                         matTooltip="Kalkulatorische Werte"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
```

Comment: You're using angular, so you should use `[disabled]="..."` to implement this, then set the state of your app accordingly in the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="condition" (click)="condition = true">...</button>
```

and in *.component.ts add row:

```
public condition = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Demo for you on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hx9acn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Try this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public isDisable: boolean = false;
  
  disableBtns() {
    this.isDisable = true;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="header-menu">
    <!-- File search -->
    <button [disabled]="isDisable" type="button" (click)="disableBtns()">
        <i class="fa fa-search" matTooltip="Filter"></i>
    </button>
    <!-- File import -->
    <button [disabled]="isDisable" type="button" (click)="disableBtns()">
        <i class="fas fa-upload" matTooltip="SuSa-Upload"></i>
    </button>
    <!-- File export -->
    <button [disabled]="isDisable" type="button" (click)="disableBtns()">
        <i class="fas fa-download" matTooltip="SuSa-Download"></i>
    </button>
    <!-- Start calculatoryBookings -->
    <button [disabled]="isDisable" type="button" (click)="disableBtns()">
        <i class="fas fa-edit" matTooltip="Kalkulatorische Werte"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved using click and disabled.
click on search button will disable all others

```
<div class="header-menu">
                <!-- File search -->
                <button type="button" [disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="isDisabled=true">
                  <!-- <i class="fa fa-search" matTooltip="Filter"></i> -->
                </button>
                <!-- File import -->
                <button type="button" [disabled]="isDisabled">
                  <i class="fas fa-upload" matTooltip="SuSa-Upload" ></i>
                </button>
                <!-- File export -->
                <button type="button" [disabled]="isDisabled" >
                  <i class="fas fa-download" matTooltip="SuSa-Download"></i>
                </button>
                <!-- Start calculatoryBookings -->
                <button type="button" [disabled]="isDisabled">
                  <i class="fas fa-edit"
                     matTooltip="Kalkulatorische Werte"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-35nyz4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementsByClassName('header-menu')[0].querySelectorAll('button').forEach(ele=>
{ ele.disabled = true;}
);

Comment: this solution for pure javascript, not for angular 2+